Bathtub install for one
I’m installing the Kolher Elmbrook tub from Home Depot, (fiberglass) my bathroom is exactly 60x120 my question is will it fit? Also do I absolutely need a cement bed? I know the size says it will but it’s just me and need as much advice as I can get. I’m not new to remodeling but it’s my first job that’s 100% me I’m most of you guys or gals remember your first.Any or All advice is welcome I ve got a ducks back.

This is really two questions.  Is the 60" dimension from stud wall to stud wall, or from drywall face to drywall face?  The instructions include a mortar bed, so you should definitely use one.

If the instructions say your need a cement bed, then you need a cement bed.
Most standard tubs are made to fit in a 60 inch opening between stud walls.  If that is what you have it will fit.
